# using proxy_pass with dynamic variables nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to use proxy_pass with nginx to mask redirects to my image CDN. I'd like to be able to go to a path like:

myserver.com/images/12345/whatever-name-goes-here.jpg

I'd like that to proxy to

http://imagecdn.com/12345.jpg

i've tried the following

```
location ~ /images/(.*)/(.*) {
      proxy_pass http://imagecdn.com/$1.jpg; 
    }
```

But i keep getting 502 errors. Any idea if this is even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using an actual redirect, such as:

```
location ~ ^/images/(.*)/(.*)$ {
    return 301 $scheme://imagecdn.com/$1.jpg;
}
```

Comment: I think I see the problem, you can't use proxy_pass in this way when the location is a regex, see doc for [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) and scroll down to "In some cases".  You have to use a rewrite rule: `location /images { rewrite ^/images/(.*)/(.*)$ $1.jpg break; proxy_pass http://imagecdn.com;}`

Comment: this is the answer i was looking for